# Create bootstrap select picker dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [bootstrap select plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/). I am populating a dynamically created select like so:

```
var select = $('<select/>', {
     'class':"selectpicker"
}).selectpicker();

for (var idx in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
        select.append('<option value=' + data[idx].id+ '>' + data[idx].Text+ '</option>');
    }
}

select.selectpicker('refresh');
```

The data is fine and a select is created, it is not recognizing the bootstrap selectpicker i am trying to create. I have a select on the same page that I do not create dynamically and it works fine.

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

How do I dynamically create a bootstrap select? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to append the `<select />` you create to the DOM before calling `selectpicker()` on it, something like this:

```
var $select = $('<select/>', {
     'class':"selectpicker"
});
for (var idx in data) {
    $select.append('<option value=' + data[idx].id + '>' + data[idx].Text + '</option>');
}

$select.appendTo('#myElement').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Note the use of `append()`, and also the removal of `hasOwnProperty` - you're already looping through the properties of the object so that method call is redundant.

Comment: gotcha...i'll try this. Thanks

Comment: Just remember `.selectpicker('refresh')` is very important thing :D

Comment: I got `.selectpicker('refresh')` is not a function error on console