# Dynamically inserting a bootstrap-select cell into a table row not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-select

I have dynamically created a table row and am inserting each cell into a the row and then into the table. All the previous cells are working (as they are simple checkbox inputs or plain text) however this row is different.

I am trying to insert a [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) dropdown into a table cell dynamically and am not having any luck. It is not throwing any errors, however it is not displaying a dropdown.

My attempt based off [this quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756959/create-bootstrap-select-picker-dynamically):

```
var cell = row.insertCell(5);
var selectCell = $('<select/>', {
    'class': "selectpicker"
});
selectCell.append("<option>Value 1</option>");
selectCell.append("<option>Value 2</option>");
selectCell.append("<option>Value 3</option>");

selectCell.appendTo(cell);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You inserting a normal `<select>`. If you want a bootstrap-select, not need to attach the plugin to it after you have added it to the DOM

Comment: Surely this is inserting a `select` with class `selectpicker` meaning the bootstrap select should be active? Either way, isn't this meant to display a normal `select` in the table row rather than nothing?

Comment: No. You need to attach the plugin after your add the element. And the code you have for adding a `<select>` element works fine (refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srxtj7ga/))

Comment: How would I go about doing that? And that is very strange considering my table row doesn't show anything in the cell.. any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why you code is not working (obviously something to do with code you have not shown us) - but to attach the plugin, you need `selectCell.selectpicker({ ... });` after you add it to the DOM

Comment: Alright I see what you mean. I'll test it tomorrow and see what happens although the code in this post is the same.. strange! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**Table**

```
<table>
  <tr id="row"></tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
var row = document.getElementById('row');
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
/*var selectCell = $('<select/>', {
    'class': "selectpicker"
});*/

var selectCell = $('<select>');
$(selectCell).addClass('selectpicker');
selectCell.append("<option>Value 1</option>");
selectCell.append("<option>Value 2</option>");
selectCell.append("<option>Value 3</option>");

selectCell.appendTo(cell);
```

Online result [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/mLLso19o/1/).